# How is unsafeWindow implemented by user script extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey, firefox-addon-webextensions, monkeypatching

Today I came across a situation where I need to make an extension to monkey-patch some objects in a web page.

However I found little to none documentation on how it can actually be achieved, I've tried using the [`userScripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/userScripts) API (currently exclusive to Firefox) but the `window` object is contextually isolated from the `window` on the HTML DOM of the page.

I know that this is possible because user script managers like GreaseMonkey implement an `unsafeWindow` object which gives the script direct access to objects in the unisolated context of the web page, thus making monkey-patching very easy.

So I would like to know how this is actually achieved. I've attempted to study the source code of an user script manager called [ViolentMonkey](https://github.com/violentmonkey/violentmonkey), I found that it defines `unsafeWindow` in [`src/injected/web/gm-api-wrapper.js:53`](https://github.com/violentmonkey/violentmonkey/blob/b110c55c3a9f566cffa0fef106a0abed68ead050/src/injected/web/gm-api-wrapper.js#L53) as a reference to the `global` object but I could not locate where this in turn is defined in the source code.

I know that this is not implemented by simply injecting a `<script>` element in the page because none is visible in the page's DOM upon my inspection.

I'm very curious about the implementation of this cool mechanism, I'm pretty sure I missed something obvious so I need your help to remove my blind-folds!

Comment: In Firefox you should use wrappedJSObject to access the page context and exportFunction to expose your code into the page context. See [Monkey patch getUserMedia in a WebExtension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62168202)

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is basically load the DOM and modify the content injecting Content Scripts.

For example to modify the following HTML:

```
<html>
     <button id="mybutton">click me</button>
     <script>
        var greeting = "hello, ";
        var button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
        button.person_name = "Bob";
        button.addEventListener(
            "click", () => alert(greeting + button.person_name + "."), false);
      </script>
</html>
```

You can inject this code:

```
var greeting = "hola, ";
var button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
button.person_name = "Roberto";
button.addEventListener(
    "click", () => alert(greeting + button.person_name + "."), false);
```

You can inject the script with dynamic or static declarations on a Chrome extension.

Here is a sample manifest.json using static declarations:

```
{
 "name": "My extension",
 ...
 "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["https://*.nytimes.com/*"],
     "css": ["my-styles.css"],
     "js": ["content-script.js"]
   }
 ],
 ...
}
```

In addition, you can check [Chrome extension's docs] for more information.